# Angular 5 Sticky Navigation Bar with no effect on scrollbar

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm trying to reproduce Navigation Bar like in [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/) site.

What I want:

[image: with NO effect on scrollbar],

What I get:

[image: with effect on scrollbar]

What did I miss in the source on [GitHub](https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io)? Where they fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of CSS is responsible for making only content area scrollable:

```
material-docs-app>app-guides, 
material-docs-app>app-homepage, 
material-docs-app>guide-viewer {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io/blob/master/src/app/material-docs-app.scss